# Entity Framework Stored Procedures and INFORMATION_SCHEMA views

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

I have a stored procedure that pulls metadata from the `INFORMATATION_SCHEMA` views in SQL Server from another database.  With EF, I'm getting the error:

> "the selected stored procedures returns no columns"

Naturally, I remembered the `SET FMTONLY OFF` command, but this did not work.  Turning it on didn't work either (I know EF does this, but it was worth a shot :-)).

Anyway, what actually finally did work is inserting the results into a table variable, and selecting the results of the table variable.  However, it didn't work with a table variable when `SET FMTONLY OFF` was set; it only works with a table variable when this statement is omitted, hence it's turned on by EF.

That is very, very strange, and I don't want to have to use a table variable.  That seems foolish to have to do it.  Is there any other way?

Thanks.

Comment: OK this helped explain why the table variable works and why you can't set FMTONLY off: "One other work around or maybe a better solution is to not use temp tables at all, if you don’t need too index those tables that is.  If you use table variables, the SET FMTONLY ON; option will not break in your stored procedure." (via http://softscenario.blogspot.com/2011/06/entiy-framework-add-function-import-get.html).